# ¿Cual es la finalidad de devolver un "ActionResult" en C# en lugar del propio objeto?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

No termino de entender la ventaja que supone devolver en un método un "ActionResult" en lugar de directamente el tipo de objeto que quieres devolver. ¿Cuál sería la ventaja y cuando debería usarlo?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Las preguntas que piden una opinion no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que atrae respuestas basadas en opiniones las cuales no encajan con el formato del sitio.